# Vertical line not draw

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to draw a centered vertical line in a scrollview. I have got two galaxy 2s one with the Android version 4.2.2 and the other with the version 2.3.7.

My results as far only works under the android version 4.2.2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test text" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

[image: example]

While using the android version 2.3.7 the view (line in the middle) is no draw.

Does anyone knows whats the problem running android 2.3.7?

Comment: Your method using a view is good. I think that a FrameLayout works better with only one direct child. Why not use a LinearLayout instead of that frame layout ?

Comment: First I used a LinearLayout, but that dind't work. Because I could center the line. When drawing the line in the relavilayout with the height wrap_content, the line disappears.

Comment: have you tried to make height of FrameLayout and scrollview fill_parent ?

Comment: Did you try using Gravity and LayoutGravity for the linear and for the relative CenterInParent and AlignParent

Comment: @Onur A. yes and that dind't work either.

Comment: hım try to give hard-coded value for <View>

Comment: @Yume117 that don't works because the view width is 4dp

Comment: @Onur A. I won't give a fixed height (yes then it works...) but i want to have a line in the middle of the screen as long as my relative layout.

Comment: The width has nothing to do with the position of the view. You can set 1dp or 10dp it wont change the position
 Edit : having a parent with Wrap_content and a child with Match_parent is problematic, you should set your container (here your framelayout) to match_parent. Then you can add some margin to make it looks better

Comment: @suizo no no don't give fixed length, i just wanted to test if it works, but as Yume117 mentions parent with wrap_content and child with match_parent can make problem, try to make them match_parent and for the vertical line doesnt seen on 2.3.7 maybe textview is hiding vertical line, so maybe youn should try to make it relative layout

Comment: Thanks for the help, I posted my solution which feels more like a hack than a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a xml only solution.

My xml looks like. Note that the view has a fixed height which will be replaced in the activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ManualStartTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Start" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/CenterRelativLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ManualNoCardTableRow" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/ManualTopGrayLine"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ManualStepTreeHeaderTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ManualStepTreeButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ManualTopGrayLine"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="3) Verifizieren" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ManualStepTreeBodyTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ManualStepTreeHeaderTextView"
                android:layout_below="@+id/ManualStepTreeHeaderTextView"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:text="Lorem alfpha alsda a,si ljkasoi kjasbas asdop1 ,aspo9ij aslkdja9s oaisdjas0pd oasdn0p9m asd0p9" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/CenterRelativLayout"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- some other content -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

the xml generates the following view.

[image]

If you want to have a dynamically height of you line (view) you can add the following method to your activity. Which will set the height of the line to the same height as the RelativeLayout.

```
@Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus == true) {
            View manualTopGrayLine = findViewById(R.id.ManualTopGrayLine);
            RelativeLayout rlayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.CenterRelativLayout);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) manualTopGrayLine.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = rlayout.getHeight();
            manualTopGrayLine.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);            
        }
    }
```